# htaccess make additional (hidden) request in background

Tags: .htaccess

I want a script on my server to excecute whenever there is a certain string found in the GET parameter. However I dont want the user to notice any of this as the server should serve the requested page like usual.

Is this possible?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} matchthis
# Make hidden request
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^foo=bar(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^matchthis/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}?foo=bar [L,QSA,NC]
```

This rule is adding a query parameter `foo=bar` if requested URI is `/matchthis`. This change will be hidden from the user since I'm not using `R` flag here **hence it is an internal forward instead of an external redirect**.